# VBA Code for Conditional Copying of Columns Not Adjacent to each other

Tags: vba, excel, conditional-statements

Project Master

[image: Project Master]

In MS Excel using VBA, I would like some help on conditional copying between worksheets within the same workbook. As per the attached image, I have a master list of projects on the worksheet "Master".  For all the projects that have a "yes" in column I (Defect), I would like to copy the values in columns A (Works Package Issue Date), B (Project No.), E (City) and H (Contract Value) to another worksheet "Defects", within the same workbook.
Can you please provide a coding which could:
a) collapse all the rows so there is no blank rows in "Defects" worksheet; and
b) leave all the rows so if the "Defect" column has a "No", the relevant row from the "Master" worksheet is copied as a blank row in the "Defect" worksheet, 
if possible.
Please help me with the coding - I have very basic knowledge of macros, and in a process of learning how to code. 
Thanks & Regards, CK

Comment: Sorry I haven't put my codes earlier - will note to put mine going forward. New to the site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Sub CopyValues()

'Declare variables
'Declare sheet variables
Dim Masterws as Worksheet
Dim Defectws as worksheet

'Declare counter variables
Dim I as Integer
Dim n as Integer

'Set value of sheet variables
Set Masterws=ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Master")
Set Defectws=ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Defects")

'Set value of counter to track first available row on Defects sheet
n=1

'Start a For loop to check each row on Master sheet, starting with row 2
For I = 2 to WorksheetFunction.CountA(Masterws.Columns.EntireColumn(1))

    'If the cells in row I, column I have a value of, "Yes," then execute some code. If not, continue on.
    If Cells(I, "I").value= "Yes" Then

        'Set the value of cells in row n of the Defects sheet to the corresponding values of row I in the Master sheet. If n is replaced with I, then the value of cells in row I on Defects will be set to the values of Row I on Master, leaving blank rows where no, "Yes," was found because no copying took place.
        Defectws.Cells(n,"A").Value=Masterws.cells(I,"A")
        Defectws.Cells(n,"B").Value=Masterws.cells(I,"B")
        Defectws.Cells(n,"C").Value=Masterws.cells(I,"E")
        Defectws.Cells(n,"D").Value=Masterws.cells(I,"H")

        'Add 1 to the n counter. The next time a row is found in the Master sheet with, "Yes," it will be written to the next available row down on the Defects sheet.
        n=n+1

    End If

'End of the For loop. Move on to the next row on Master sheet
Next

End Sub
```